# Summing the binomial pmf over $n$, part 2

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

After the great answers I got to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406168/), I tried summing a similar-looking series using the same strategies ($k \geq 0, \alpha > 1, p \in (0,1)$):

$$ \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \quad = \quad p^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {k+n \choose k} \frac{(1-p)^n}{(n+k)^{\alpha}}$$

This is just the original series with each term deflated by $n^{\alpha}$. However, I didn't make much headway. The extra term breaks Byron's nice negative binomial interpretation, and finding the ordinary generating function for $\{{k+n \choose k} n^{-\alpha}\}_{n \geq 0}$ wasn't obvious to me.

If anyone sees how to do this, can I get **just a hint**? Been dogging me for hours.